# How to design a proper android app? Tips and tricks

Tags: android, user-interface, graphics

This topic is perhaps more related to designers and who makes graphic design for Android devices.

For some reasons, I haven't found on Internet any proper tutorial or explanation on how to design a proper application, such as the twitter application, DropBox application, etc.
There are many talks only about development, but no tips about how to find the best and comfortable ways to design for many screen sizes, resolutions, and densities. (As far as I see Android has many ratios, relations for width and height.)

Designers! How do you design the best layout for graphic elements?
How are you testing your design, Eclipse or other tools?
Is there on internet any android design community?
Are there any UI touch-smart-phone specific tips?

If in addition to your answers you have any tips and suggestion, please share it here!
Please share whatever you can!

I and other designers who just steeped in this area will much appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you seen [this video](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=M1ZBjlCRfz0)?

Answer (score 0):

The design process goes something like Illustrator -> Photoshop -> PNGs
I also like to use Fireworks for a quick mockup now and then.

To start off with you'll want:

- UI guidelines: [Android UI Guidelines](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/&ei=XSCGTcWNJ4yDhQeEvP3BBA&usg=AFQjCNE6Dm9Gi37OBeUWGSTe9eiXYA1YGw&sig2=4gNi7SbGmjflUUdwL7caDg)
- Established design patterns: [Google IO 2010](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html), [Android Patterns](http://www.androidpatterns.com/)
- Mockups: [Smashing Mag](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/18/android-gui-psd-vector-kit/), [ChethStudios](http://www.chethstudios.net/2010/03/google-nexus-one-android-gui-psd-packs.html)

In Eclipse you can use tools like PixelPerfect to ensure everything is just right, and make good use of NinePatch drawables.

As for smart-phone/Android specific tips: go watch a bunch of the Google IO vids, and play around with a load of existing iPhone/Android apps - which ones do you like best and what is about the interface that makes you like it?